# Adding another jquery function to the same form / list isn't working

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, drop-down-menu

Ive got a problem with a jquery function (it does not work) that allows me to check/uncheck all checkboxes. 
I think it doesn't work because another jquery function blocks its functionality.

So i got a form which has 4 'subjects' with a drop-down list of checkboxes. To let the checkboxes 'drop-down' i added a jquery function. Though, i also want to include a select/deselect all checkbox in each of the 4 subjects drop-down lists.

SO my html code is as follows: 
**NOTE: I only pasted the html code of the 4th subject drop-down list in (list4)**

```
<div id="list4" class="dropdown-check-list">
        <span class="anchor">Select stage of Living Lab</span>
        <ul class="items">
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_stage[]" value="Starting phase" />Starting phase</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_stage[]" value="Running phase" />Running phase</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_stage[]" value="Completed" />Completed</li>  
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="select-all" id="select-all" value="Select/deselect all"/>Select/deselect all</li>  
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**The Jquery code that allows me to drop down the menu is as follows (note that in here i pasted the code for all 4 the subject lists):**

```
var checkList = document.getElementById('list1');
        checkList.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function (evt) {
            if (checkList.classList.contains('visible'))
                checkList.classList.remove('visible');
            else
                checkList.classList.add('visible');
        }

        var checkList2 = document.getElementById('list2');
        checkList2.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function (evt) {
            if (checkList2.classList.contains('visible'))
                checkList2.classList.remove('visible');
            else
                checkList2.classList.add('visible');
        }

        var checkList3 = document.getElementById('list3');
        checkList3.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function (evt) {
            if (checkList3.classList.contains('visible'))
                checkList3.classList.remove('visible');
            else
                checkList3.classList.add('visible');
        }

        var checkList4 = document.getElementById('list4');
        checkList4.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function (evt) {
            if (checkList4.classList.contains('visible'))
                checkList4.classList.remove('visible');
            else
                checkList4.classList.add('visible');
        }
```

**The Jquery code that should select/deselect all the checkboxes is as follows:**

```
$('#select_all').click(function(event) {
        if(this.checked) {
            // Iterate each checkbox
            $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = true;
            });
        }
        else {
            $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = false;
            });
        }
     });
```

This doesn't work though, the drop-down of the list code works but the select/deselect code doesn't.. Also when i paste the select/deselect code before the drop-down code, then the drop-down code isn't working..

Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That first block is the most *un-jQuery* `jQuery` code I have seen :) If you are going to use jQuery then please *use* jQuery for most operations.

Comment: Followup: that first block of code can be reduced by about 80% using jQuery, but I am not 100% sure what it actually does. Can you explain its purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple typo:

i.e. you have `$('#select_all')` instead of `$('#select-all')` so it does not match the id.

*But I will followup with a complete rewrite to show how to better do some of these things*

### Select-all the jQuery way:

A better way to write this *select-all* behavior is to find a common ancestor of the `checkbox` clicked (using `closest`), then check all the related ones. This example will work for any number of checkbox lists on the page.

```
$('.select-all').change(function (event) {
    var $list = $(this).closest('.dropdown-check-list');
    $list.find(':checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Note I had to use a class instead of an id for the select-all checkboxes as ID's must be unique and are less useful in jQuery..

### Update:

Once I figured out what it did, I replaced the entire first block of Javascript/jQuery code with this http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/c7ydfz1k/5/:

```
$('.dropdown-check-list .anchor').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.dropdown-check-list').toggleClass("visible");
});
```

**Notes:**

- You can use `click` or `change` for checkboxes, but there are side-effects if you ever simulate clicks using code. I use `change` simply because it seems more appropriate.
- You should uses class when possible as IDs are unique and less useful. The ids in the example are not actually needed/used.

*My advice is learn jQuery from end-to-end and improve/shorten/simplify existing Javascript code where you can.*

Comment: Thank you for your great reply! About your advice, yep i still need to really dive into the Jquery code! Thanks!